# removing namespace from xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I have an xml as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Query_advanced>
<Query>hy</Query>
  <Attribute Name1="Patient's Age" Value1="23" xmlns="xyz"/>
  <Attribute Name1="Patient's Birth Date" Value1="24/12/1988" xmlns="xyz"/>
  <Attribute Name1="Patient's Name" Value1="xyz" xmlns="xyz" />
</Query_advanced>
```

I need to read through the xml to get the values of Name1 and of Value1, but im unable to do so with the xmlns there. Is there any way i could do so? Ive tried using:

```
XmlNamespaceManager xnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
xnm.RemoveNamespace("Attribute", "xyz");
```

Comment: You don't want to remove the namespace. You want to be able to find the nodes with the namespace present.

Add the "xyz" namespace to the XmlNamespaceManager, then use it in your XPath query.

Comment: Hi, @JohnSaunders Im new, not too sure how to go about. Could you guide me as to how i could? I just need to be able to read the two values. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your current code that isn't working? Also, what .NET version are you using?

Comment: XmlDocument xdoc=new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.Load("C:\\Users\\Hy\\Desktop\\hy.xml");
            XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Users\\Hy\\Desktop\\hy.xml");
            textReader.Read();
            // If the node has value
            while (textReader.Read())
            {XmlNamespaceManager xnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
                xnm.RemoveNamespace("hh", "xyz");
                xdoc.Save("C:\\Users\\Hy\\Desktop\\try.xml");}       Im currently using .NET 3.5.

Comment: Wow. Get rid of the textreader code. You already read the document using Load. How were you trying to find the nodes. The code you posted only shows how you tried and failed to remove the namespaces.

Comment: @JohnSaunders i had the textreader to read the nodes. haven't done the part of reading yet, i thought after i checked "try.xml" i would, since it wouldn't have the namespace? not sure if thats the right way to go about!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THanks for all your suggestions! I managed to do it this way:

private void QueryXML()
        {

```
        XmlDocument query_xml = new XmlDocument();
        query_xml.Load("Query_1.xml");
        XmlNodeList elements = query_xml.GetElementsByTagName("Attribute");
        string[] s = new string[elements.Count];


        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
        {
            string attrVal = elements[i].Attributes["Value1"].Value;
        Console.Writeline(attrval)
```

}

Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you've not to remove the namespace, but you've to add it to the XmlNameSpaceManager, in order to use a prefix (as @John Saunders comments), for example, in a XPath expression.

Try this:

```
XmlNamespaceManager xnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
xnm.AddNamespace("a", "xyz");

// Cycle through the Attribute nodes
foreach (XmlNode node in xdoc.SelectNodes("//Query_advanced/a:Attribute", xnm)) 
{
    // And read the attributes of the node
    string NameAttribute = node.Attributes["Name1"].Value;
    string ValueAttribute = node.Attributes["Value1"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `XmlReader` or `XmlTextReader` if you have a file.

Here an example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

In your example `Attribute` is a xml tag, not a namespace. `Name1` and `Value1` are xml attributes of the tag `Attribute`.

So you need to read the attributes of the tag `Attribute`.

Let `xmlString` is the xml you want to parse:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
{
    while(reader.ReadToFollowing("Attribute")){ //loop read Attribute tag
       reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
       string Name1 = reader.Value; //do something with Name1
       reader.MoveToNextAttribute();
       string Value1 = reader.Value; //do something with Value1
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @max i did try this, but this is what i get:                       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Query_advanced>
<Query>hy</Query>                                                       <Attribute>                                                         <Attribute></Attribute>                                              </Attribute>                                                        </Attribute>                                                        </Query_advanced>  What can i do next? Thanks!

Comment: Follow the msdn example:
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("Attribute");
    reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
    string genre = reader.Value; //read Name1
...